# Alphabetical order a 2d array

Tags: c, string, multidimensional-array, openvms

I'm doing an exercise in C with strings, I have to order some words taken by a text.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main(){
        int cch=0, cw=0, i, j, w=0, ord=0, f=0; //counter and index
        char testo[80];
        char alfa[50][25];
        char swap[25];

        printf("Write the test:\n");
        gets(testo);

        if(testo[0]!='\0'){
                cw=1;   
                for(i=0;testo[i]!='\0';i++){
                        cch++;
                        if(testo[i]==' '){
                                cw++;
                        }
                }
        }

        for(i=0;i<cch;i++){
                if(testo[i]==' ' && testo[i+1]==' '){
                        cw--;
                }
        }

        if(testo[0]==' '){
                cw--;
                w--;
        }

        printf("\nIn the test there are %d characters\n", cch);
        printf("In the test there are %d words\n", cw);

        if(cw>0){
                printf("\nUsed words:\n");
                for(j=0;j<cch;j++){
                        if(testo[j]==' ' && testo[j+1]==' '){
                                //nothing to do       
                        }
                        else{
                                if(testo[j]!=' '){
                                        alfa[w][f]=testo[j];
                                        f++;
                                }
                                else if(testo[j]=='\0'){
                                        alfa[w][f]='\0';
                                        f=0;
                                        w=0;
                                }
                                else{
                                        alfa[w][f]='\0';
                                        w++;
                                        f=0;
                                }
                        }
                }

                for(i=0;i<cw;i++){
                        printf("%d> %s\n", i+1, &alfa[i]);
                }

                //order
                f=1;
                printf("\nWord used in alphabetical order:\n");
                while(f==1){
                        f=0;
                        for(i=0;i<cw-1;i++){
                                ord=strcmp(alfa[i],alfa[i+1]);
                                if(ord>-1){
                                        strcpy(swap,alfa[i]);
                                        strcpy(alfa[i],alfa[i+1]);
                                        strcpy(alfa[i+1],swap);
                                        f=1;
                                }       
                        }
                }

                for(i=0;i<cw;i++){
                        printf("%d> %s\n", i+1, alfa[i]);
                }
        }
        else{
                printf("You haven't written any word.\n");
        }
}
```

The problem is that if there are two identical words, and the words are more than 2, I have a loop and I don't have any result, what should I do?
Tested on OpenVMS.
Thank you.

PS: I know that there are plenty of bug at the moment, but I'm having problem to solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(ord>-1){
    /* ... */
}
```

If both words are the same `strcmp` will return `0`. This will swap both words until your next power bill comes in and you shut your program down. Instead, check whether the result is greater than zero:

```
if(ord > 0){
    /* ... */
}
```

See also: [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp)

Comment: @AlessioMTX: Happens to everyone. Further remarks: `strtok` will make your word counting much easier and can be used with `strlen`.